# firebase react native expo : none of these files exist

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I just set up firebase with my react native expo code and downloaded everything (I think) but an error keeps popping up Building JavaScript bundle: error
ERROR
16:09
Unable to resolve module ./prebuilt.rn-bdc79115.
if anyone can help that would be great[image]

Comment: what version of firebase did you install?

Comment: i installed npm install --save @react-native-firebase/app

Comment: https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/ - `expo install firebase`

Answer (score 1):

If someone runs into that, it happened to me because I installed firebase with npm while using expo instead of expo install firebase.

```
expo install firebase
```

After that make sure your import on the project are correct, instead of

```
import "@firebase/auth";
```

for example youll need

```
import "firebase/auth";
```

And the main import of firebase should be

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

After all of that, delete node modules completly,
run `npm install` again, ofc couse with the new package json with the expo installation of firebase, and go ahead and start the project again with `npm start`

Comment: That really helped. Thanks :)